# Convert a string into a double, and a int. How to?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble converting a string into a double. 
My string has been declared using the "string" function, so my string is:

```
string marks = "";
```

Now to convert it to a double I found somewhere on the internet to use word.c_str(), and so I did. I called it and used it like this:

```
doubleMARK = strtod( marks.c_str() );
```

This is similar to the example I found on the web:

```
n1=strtod( t1.c_str() );
```

Apparently, that's how it's done. But of course, it doesn't work. I need another parameter. A pointer I believe? But I'm lost at this point as to what I'm suppose to do. Does it need a place to store the value or something? or what?

I also need to convert this string into a integer which I have not begun researching as to how to do, but once I find out and if I have errors, I will edit this out and post them here.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `strtod()`?

Comment: No I have not, but I'll get on that right away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Was there a reason you're not using [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)? They are at least 9 levels more powerful than flimsy `strtod`.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/7Z2zc)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  string s = "-1";
  double d = stod(s);
  int i = stoi(s);
  cout << s << " " << d << " " << i << endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
-1 -1 -1
```

---

If you must use `strtod`, then just pass `NULL` as the second parameter. According to cplusplus.com:

> If [the second parameter] is not a null pointer, the function also sets the value pointed by endptr to point to the first character after the number.

And it's not required to be non-`NULL`.

Comment: lmao. Uhm, the reason behind why I haven't used those is because I've never learned them, or heard of them, and they never came up on my google adventure. Care to explain how they work? or should I go back to my great voyage across google? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Robsta yes, I only learned about them here on SO. You can click on the name of the function in the answer to go to the doc page for each of them. If you can't decipher the documentation then let me know and I'll give an example

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks very much, I never mind people editing my answers to improve them.

Comment: I happen to like strtod () :)

Comment: From my understanding, all you need is the string you'd like to convert, and a pointer? Then you get the return value you so desired?
How'd I do?

Comment: @Robsta please read the update, I've explained how to use `strtod` if you need to

Comment: Well then. That code example explained a lot. Thank you, guess you don't need that pointer I was talking about. I appreciate the time.

Comment: @Robsta you do for `strtod`, but that's not `strtod`, it's `stod`, a completely different function

Comment: ``std::stoi`` is a wrapper around ``std::strto[u]l``, and ``std::stod`` is a wrapper around ``std::strtod`` (see the standard section 21.5 "Numeric conversions")

Comment: Something to be aware of is that `std::strtod` has a no exception guarantee whereas `std::stod` throws a couple of different exceptions. So, depending on how you deal with error handling, it might mean one or the other is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the Bad Old Dark Days of C, I'd do something ugly and unsafe like this:

```
char sfloat[] = "1.0";
float x;
sscanf (sfloat, "%lf", &x);
```

In C++, you might instead do something like this:

```
// REFERENCE: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231054
include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
bool from_string(T& t, 
                 const std::string& s, 
                 std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&))
{
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  return !(iss >> f >> t).fail();
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  float f;

  // the third parameter of from_string() should be 
  // one of std::hex, std::dec or std::oct
  if(from_string<int>(i, std::string("ff"), std::hex))
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "from_string failed" << std::endl;
  }

  if(from_string<float>(f, std::string("123.456"), std::dec))
  {
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "from_string failed" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Personally, though, I'd recommend this:

> http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/137731-convert-string-float
>
> There are two ways. C gives you strtod which converts between a char
>   array and double:

```
// C-ish: 
input2 = strtod(input.c_str(), NULL);
```

> The C++ streams provide nice conversions to and from a variety of
>   types. The way to use strings with streams is to use a stringstream:

```
// C++ streams: 
double input2;
istringstream in(input); 
input >> input2;
```

Comment: This. This also help a crap load. Man, thank you for you time and input, I appreciate it (:

Answer (score 1):

We can define a `stringTo()` function,

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
T stringTo(const std::string& s) {
  T x;
  std::istringstream in(s);
  in >> x;
  return x;
}
```

Then, use it like

```
std::cout << stringTo<double>("-3.1e3") << " " << stringTo<int>("4");
```